# no such table: Entry_table

Tags: android

I am getting error in table 2 i.e in entry table which says no such table Entry_table when i insert data into table it goes to the Toast database error the error link takes me to entry table where i am inserting data
 Here is my error:

```
     01-15 11:40:52.638 3420-3420/com.example.nitin.mithun E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Entry_table
            01-15 11:40:52.644 3420-3420/com.example.nitin.mithun E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting AMOUNT=2 CARET=2 BALANCE=2 AMOUNT_PAID=2
                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Entry_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Entry_table(AMOUNT,CARET,BALANCE,AMOUNT_PAID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                                        at com.example.nitin.mithun.DatabaseHelper.insertdatat(DatabaseHelper.java:75)
                                                                                        at com.example.nitin.mithun.Entry$1.onClick(Entry.java:45)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)


Entry.java
```

this is my activity:

```
package com.example.nitin.mithun;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Entry extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnsbmt1;
    Spinner spiner2;
    EditText milkcaret,amount, amountp,bal;


    DatabaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);
        mydb=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btnsbmt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit2);
        spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        milkcaret=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1_de);
        amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2_de);
        amountp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3_de);
        bal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_de);


        adddata2();

    }

    public void adddata2(){
        btnsbmt1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean inserteddata = mydb.insertdatat(milkcaret.getText().toString(),amount.getText().toString(),amountp.getText().toString(),bal.getText().toString());

                        if (inserteddata)
                            Toast.makeText(Entry.this, "data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Entry.this, "database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

and this my database helper:

```
    package com.example.nitin.mithun;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * Created by Nitin on 12/16/2015.
     */
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Sales.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME1="Insert_table";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME2="Entry_table";




        public static final String COL_ID="ID";
        public static final String Col_NAME="NAME";



        public static final String Col_CARET="CARET";
        public static final String Col_AMOUNT="AMOUNT";
        public static final String Col_AMOUNT_PAID="AMOUNT_PAID";
        public static final String Col_BALANCE="BALANCE";




        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + " (ID_NAME INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CARET INTEGER, AMOUNT INTEGER,AMOUNT_PAID INTEGER,BALANCE INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Insert_table(ID_NAME))");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME2);
            onCreate(db);

        }
        public boolean insertdata(String name){
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(Col_NAME, name);
            long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null,contentValues);
            if(result== -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }


        public boolean insertdatat(String caret,String amount,String amount_paid,String balance ){
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(Col_CARET,caret);
            contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT,amount);
            contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT_PAID,amount_paid);
            contentValues.put(Col_BALANCE,balance);

            long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME2,null,contentValues);
            if(result== -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the application first then install it again.Then this will run smoothly.

Comment: thanks it worked , but what was the problem ? can you explain ?

Comment: it is because you are inserting a value and table was not created at that time.

Comment: #bipin marked it as correct answer if it worked for you.